# how to read field with Chinese

Tags: plc4x

I'm trying to read some node data from keyserverex using

```
HelloPlc4xRead
```

then I got this

[image]

here's my cmds :
the first cmd failed , it contains Chinese words

```
connection-string=opcua:tcp://192.168.239.128:49320 -field-addresses=ns=2;s=chan1.device1.标记2
```

and the second cmd  works fine

```
-connection-string=opcua:tcp://192.168.239.128:49320 -field-addresses=ns=2;s=chan1.device1.mark1
```

any chance could I use Chinese words making it work  fine .

I also using eclipse milo client to read the same fields , it's all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just closing the loop this issue was fixed by a PR on the develop branch last year. Thank you if that was you :)
https://github.com/apache/plc4x/pull/668

Officially this was included in the latest release 0.11 which as released a few weeks ago.